# How can I print content of sublists with specific format in Python?

Tags: python, list, printing

I have a list with several sublists (unknown number), e.g.

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I want to print the content of sublists, without brackets, in parentheses, separated with commas and gaps like this

```
(1, 2, 3)
(4, 5, 6)
```

I have tried using

```
for i in range(0, len(l)):
   print('(',*l[i],')')
```

but it does not work. It just gives me:

```
( 1 2 3 )
( 4 5 6 )
```

which is not what I want

Any idea how I can get the result I need?

Comment: `print(*map(tuple, l))`?

Comment: Yes, that is what i wanted. Thank you very much

Comment: For what it's worth the `sep` and `end` parameters of the print function would also have helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
for l in a:
    print(tuple(l))
```

Comment: You can't initialize a list like that.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
for i in l:
   print('('+",".join(map(str, i))+')')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of ways to do it:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]  
>>> print(*map(tuple, l), sep='\n')
(1, 2, 3)
(4, 5, 6)
>>>
>>> for sub_l in l:
        print(tuple(sub_l))


(1, 2, 3)
(4, 5, 6)
```